# How to get list of all members with a role(Online and Offline) in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to write a command for my bot that can get all members of a role, irrelevant of whether or not the are online. As of yet I have tried with variety of ways, including:

`message.guild.roles.get('someRoleId').members.map(m=>m.user.id);`

and the same using the `.roles.find('name', 'someRoleName').`

Thou these only seem to give me the online members. Therefor I'm wandering if there is a way to get all relevant members, no mater activity state.

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it right.
What you need to do is

```
message.guild.roles.get('someRoleID').members.map(m => m.user.id); // change "m.id" to "m.user.id"
```

Comment: The thing here is, that, in my cases, it does not get me the offline members. It will only create a list of the online members. But thank you for pointing out a typing mistake in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you

```js
    let role = message.mentions.roles.first();
    if (!role) role = message.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.id == args[0]);
    if (!role) return message.reply("That role not exist!");
    const listMembers = [];
    role.members.forEach((user) => {
      listMembers.push(user.user.tag);
    });

    return message.channel.send(listMembers.join(", "));
```

It works by mentioning the role or with the id

Leoncito is **Online**, Elly **Offline**

[image: Test of command]

Comment: Like for Mr Allen, this only seem to get the online members of the discord, while I must get the offline ones as well. Thou I thank you for the help.

Comment: @TheVoidBeing I did the respective tests, and it returned the members online and offline

Comment: I don't really get how it can work for you, but I just get an empty list. Having tested it a bit more, it would seem that I can only get my own role, with only my self in it. So I believe I'll find a way to rephrase my question. But again thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same problem. I assume you are using Discord js v13?
With the new update you can't access everything so easily.
You need to add *"GUILD_PRESENCES"* in you're intents.
Then after this you get all members offline and online.